# IE7 memory leak when using jquery ajax calls

Tags: jquery, ajax, memory, settimeout, memory-leaks

I have a web application that does an ajax call every second to refresh the page's state
and I'm experiencing serious memory leak issues with IE7 and jQuery(1.7.1) ajax calls.

To test the memory leak i created a html test page that all it does is run the "refreshState" function on document ready.

The "refreshState" function doesn't do much except from making the ajax call and 
setting the next time the function will run through setTimeOut function.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var url = "http://localhost/QuotesService/QuotesService.svc/GetModel";

    function refreshState() {
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            cache: false,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                //refresh page data(wasn't activated while testing for memory leaks)
                data = null;
            }
        });

        setTimeout(function () { refreshState() }, 1000);
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        refreshState();
    });
</script>
```

Is there a better way to implement this functionality that will eliminate the memory leaks?

Thanks
Ido

Comment: Are you using the most recent jQuery version?

Comment: Please define "memory leak". The raising usage of memory is not a leak.

Comment: You really have to describe how you've determined there is a memory leak.  What exact tests have you done that make you sure there is a memory leak?  It is normal for memory to increase some across multiple ajax calls (to some limit) because of browsing caching, general usage of the memory pool, etc...

Comment: The memory increases infinitely so my guess is that it's a memory leak

Answer (score 0):

Unless it's stricly necessary it's sharp on every second, maybe it helps putting the setTimeout inside the jQuery success function. This way you avoid having too many Ajax calls at the same time in case one of them "jams". If you decide to go with this I'd also recommend adding the error-function, which also sets a timeout. That way an error will not break the cycle and it's able to "reboot itself".

Answer (score 0):

I should imagine the leak is due to the fact that the AJAX call takes longer than 1s, therefore each call is being stacked up.

Do you REALLY need this to update every second? Try it with a 5 or 10 second interval, and also add an `interval - 1` timeout (example below). I'd wager your memory problem goes away.

Also, I'd add an `error` handler to your AJAX so you can better monitor any issues with the AJAX calls.

```
function refreshState() {
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        cache: false,
        dataType: "json",
        timeout: 9000, // 9s timeout
        success: function (data) {
            //refresh page data(wasn't activated while testing for memory leaks)
            data = null;
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
            console.log(status + " : " + error)
        }
    });

    setTimeout(refreshState, 10000); // 10s interval
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I do need the the update in 1 sec interval. I'v already checked and the call take couple of millisecond. Is it possible that something in the jquery ajax function itself isn't cleaned when the ajax call ends